# how to parse a json text on angular array of object .? and display it on ng 2 smart table

Tags: json, angular, ng2-smart-table

I'm doing the maintenance of an angular website, I have a problem of display in the ng2 smart table  ,  in a column it displays the json of an object, this is the error that the developer has made by receiving the list of transaction where the user and items are a  json text,
[image]
how can I parse them

ps this is the code  :

```html
this.data.doData('transaction','get').subscribe({
      next:res=>{
        console.log(res);
       this.dataSource = [...res['transactions']]
        console.log(this.dataSource)        
      },error:err=>{
        console.log(err);
        
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually you are getting the JSON string. To use it just do `JSON.parse(items)` and `JSON.parse(user)` and you will get the parsed JSON (array for the items and pbject for the user)

You can also use map in your service file and handle this parsing their so when you subscribe to the data in your component's ts file you will get the parsed form.

**UPDATE:**

Look at the quotes (quotes matching you would know from basic rules of strings, i.e. either single or double should be enclosing the main string). So when you were JSON parsing the string it wasn't taking it correct format to parse it.

[image]

Comment: can you set up minimal version on stackblitz? Their must be some minor mistake there.

Comment: And can you share your console log response of `JSON.parse(element.user)`?
And about items you cannot use a loop until its parsed. You are trying on string in your snippet.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bos21v?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table-ytzrns?file=src/app/app.component.ts try now

Comment: so  any solution ? Wahab Shah ?

Comment: Yeah so the issue is with the format you are getting. The quotes are having issues. If you look closely at the quotes in items and user they don't match. Once i resolved them it displays perfectly. I will update this and paste the screenshot

Comment: perfect I will wait for your solution  thanx

Comment: and for items ? i need to get the name of the item only

Comment: Yeah for items you have to do this same quotes thing correct (format) and then you will get the array of items, then simply use the loop

Comment: one lat thing can you send me the code xD thanx a lot

Comment: Code for what? I just did it in the console only :D. Code for items you mean or user?